# ファイルの種類について

Tags: .htaccess, テキストファイル

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像のように.htaccessが白くて透明っぽいのと、
index.phpのように緑のファイルは何が違うのでしょうか。

index.phpの中身を変えて、ファイル名を.htaccessに変更すると、
.htaccessとしての役割は果たせないのでしょうか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

名前が.(ドット)で始まるファイルは通常「隠しファイル」と呼ばれ、例えばWindowsであれば「すべてのファイルを表示」など設定しない限り、通常はファイル一覧に表示されないようになっています。
質問の画面がどこで表示されているものか分かりませんが、半透明になっているのはこの隠しファイルの状態を表しているものと思われます。